# How to browse folder in android and get the path of folder selected

Tags: java, android

When I click a button,show a file browser,I can choose a folder and return it's path.I get this path to copy file to that path.

But I have no idea of How I could implement this.

I have yet looking for this question in Stackoverflow but I haven't find a clear answer to my question.

I saw some libary of filebrowserview like "https://github.com/psaravan/FileBrowserView",but not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use intent for that!

First start start activity for result like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Override this method in your activity, it will get called when activity you just started returns. You can handle result codes such as canceled or successful.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     String Fpath = data.getDataString();
    //TODO handle your request here
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Another approach is to use library such as [NoNonsense-FilePicker](https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker).

Comment: but if user dont have file explorer?how to do ,  i want to make a simple file explorwe.

Comment: This still a file browser, not a directory/folder browser! I am not able to choose a directory with this.

Comment: @JamesPoulose did you find the answer to this problem?

Comment: @sam_k - Sadly, nothing easy! With the bits and pieces i got from multiple code snippets, i finally had to write my own _directory selector_. I still have issues browsing external cards.

Comment: What's your min sdk version here? You can use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE if you do not have any problem with min sdk 21

Comment: The code from the solution works for me by using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` instead of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` when declaring the `Intent`. Yes the min SDK should be 21 then.

Comment: @abggcv I have minSdk 21 but I'm getting "ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE typ=file/* }" exception